# Создание USA акаунта для возможности продавать приложения

Tags: android

Возник такой вопрос в свете того, что граждане моей страны НЕ могут продавать приложения на Андроид Маркете. Кто то уже сталкивался с необходимостью регистрации зарубежного аккаунта?

Возможно кто то регистрировал аккаунт не в США, а в России? Как выводите деньги?

В общем просьба поделиться опытом в этом деле. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Была такая тема пару лет назад в России, когда нельзя было продавать с российским аккаунтом. Была масса схем завязанных на каких-то американских знакомых и проч., но все эти схемы откровенно пахнут кидаловом. Я в общем помучившись с такими схемами плюнул на все и пошел в сторону свободных приложений со рекламной схемой монетизации. Благо их сейчас много Smaato, AdMob и проч.

В общем совет - двигайтесь в эту сторону. Не верьте сказкам, что как тока откроется возможность постить платные приложения то сразу будет вам манна небесная - фигня все это. Вы сначала попробуйте на бесплатных приложениях получить несколько десятков тысяч закачек, тогда можно подумать о платных приложениях.

Comment: Спасибо, но тут возникает вопрос что если я захочу потом сделать "про" версию приложения без рекламы, а акаунт на котором находится приложение уже будет "испорчен" неправильной страной. Или потом можно будет поменять страну акаунта? Я честно говоря до сих пор слабо понимаю как она определяется.

Comment: @Romeneros я же объяснил уже - сначала предъявите народу аппу с > 10 тыс. закачек, после этого уже можно будет думать как ее монетизировать. А то получается про то как делить шкуру неубитого медведя :)

Comment: Я прошу прощения, но не получается, т.к. в моем случае модель монетизации может напрямую влиять на функционал программы плюс я уже привел пример, когда "делить шкуру" медведя можно так и не начать, потому что аккаунт не из нужной страны был изначально. Кроме того есть программы, которые в принципе невозможно монетизировать рекламой.

Comment: @Romeneros попробуйте выставить приложение на апп стор Amazon'а, конечно там закачек поменьше, но ничто не мешает выставить бесплатную на маркет и из бесплатной проги сделать линк на платную в Amazon'е

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но это все же не то